# Laravel authentication fail

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

What am I doing wrong? The authentication works but does not store the session (but the sessions are working correctly) no matter what, the conection to the database is correct, everything for me looks correct, linked  but does not work.

```
Route::get('login', function(){
    return View::make('user.login');
});


Route::post('login', function(){

    if (Auth::attempt( array('user' => Input::get('user'), 'password' => Input::get('password') ), true )){
        return Redirect::to('home');
    }else{
        return Redirect::to('login')->with('error', 'blah blah');
    }

});




Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{

    Route::get('home', function(){
        echo 'welcome ' . '<br />' . PHP_EOL;

        echo 'welcome '. Auth::user()->name . ', your Id is: '.Auth::user()->id ;
    });
});
```

********--------------------------************

```
<?php
//testing session if it's working
if (Session::has ( 'asdf')) {
    Session::put('asdf', Session::get('asdf') + 1);
} else {
    Session::put('asdf', 1);
}

echo Session::get ( 'asdf' );

//testing authentication
if (Auth::check())
{
    echo 'The user is logged in...';
}

?>

@if (Session::has('error'))
<span>{{ Session::get('error') }}</span>
@endif


{{ Form::open(array( 'url' => 'login')) }}

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ Form::label('user', 'User'); }}</td>
    <td>{{ Form::text('user'); }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ Form::label('password', 'Password'); }}</td>
    <td>{{ Form::password('password'); }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">{{ Form::submit('Go!'); }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

********** - Model - ****************

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {


/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'user';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password');

/**
 * Get the unique identifier for the user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}

/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReminderEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

}
```

******* *table* *******

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id_user` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `unread_messages` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `state` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `zip_code` char(5) NOT NULL,
  `social_security` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `birth_date` date NOT NULL,
  `salary` float(4,2) NOT NULL,
  `card_number` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `lang` enum('en','es') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'en',
  `user_type` enum('admin','user') NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('ON','OFF') NOT NULL,
  `id_branch` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it redirect you to the home page?

```
echo 'welcome '. Auth::user()->name . ', your Id is: '.Auth::user()->id ;
```

What does this output?

---

Answer:

```
protected $primaryKey = "id_user";
```

Added to User Model

Comment: It redirect to my home page, but the home page when I call the filter "auth", it return fail (when the login was successful), so redirect to my login page again.

That code is for show the user's name and its Id (http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users) stored in the database

Comment: Could you post your User Model ? This could be where the issue is. The code itself seems to be okay.

Comment: I update the post with de User Model, plus the table in the database

Comment: protected $primaryKey = "id_user";

Comment: try adding that to the model.. a few other notes... I would change the table name to Users instead of User.. I would also update that in the model.. change id_user to just id.. maybe add email field to the table and try doing the login on the front end with email and password instead of the user field & password.